# URL parameter in Java code in Oracle ADF

Tags: java, oracle-adf

I've got strange problem. I have one JSF page with two controls:
- InputText
- Button

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<f:view xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:af="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/faces/rich">
<af:document title="view12.jsf" id="d1">
    <af:messages id="m1"/>
    <af:form id="f1">

        <af:inputText label="Label 1" id="it98" value="#{param.test}" editable="always"/>
        <af:commandButton actionListener="#{bindings.przekierowanie.execute}" text="przekierowanie"
                          disabled="#{!bindings.przekierowanie.enabled}" id="cb1"/>
    </af:form>
</af:document>
```

And I want to initialize the InputText with parameter from URL (param name is test - value="#{param.test}"). In JSF page everything is fine. But after clicking button I have to read the value from InputText in Java Code, so I have URL:

```
http://127.0.0.1:7101/Application6-ViewController-context-root/faces/view12.jsf?test=asd
```

and my Java code which is executed after clicking button is:

```
public String przekierowanie() {
    Map <String,String> map=FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
    String tttValue=map.get("test");
    System.err.println("test:" + tttValue);
return null;
}
```

but this doesn't work... Everytime I get null when I click the button. Could you tell me why and How to obtain this value, from InputTex in my java function?

Answer (score 0):

Implements `PagePhaseListener` in your Managed Bean and use below code to access URL parameter.

Example:

```
public void beforePhase(PagePhaseEvent pagePhaseEvent) {
    if (pagePhaseEvent.getPhaseId() == Lifecycle.PREPARE_MODEL_ID) {
        testVar = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("test");
    }
}
```

I'm using Jdev 11.1.2.0.0

Answer (score 0):

May be because you are returning only NULL .

```
public String przekierowanie() {
    Map <String,String> map=FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
    String tttValue=map.get("test");
    System.err.println("test:" + tttValue);
**return null**;
}
```